# Need to prevent dw-buffer-122.temp (storing inside machine Temp folder) creation while running mule application?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave

While I am running mule application which contains dataweave component , creating Temp file like : dw-buffer-3756726.tmp . Another thing is , application Zip package which is running under the  server ,same temp (I mean zip package name and Temp file name same  ) folder gets created inside Temp folder .
   But I don't want temp files for dataweave or mule Application.
   Anyone please suggest me how I can escape this situation.

Comment: You can deal with the dataweave buffer size https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-memory-management. In some situations weave won't close the stream and leaving orphaned tmp files. Mule descriped a workaround in a support issue https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/No-space-left-on-device-error-when-XmlToXMLStreamReader-is-used-in-application.

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue fixed in bugfixes releases of Mule Runtime. If you are using any release previous to 3.8.5 you should upgrade. Otherwise wait for 3.9.0 to be released.